# Make a param optional in an angularjs resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a param optional in an angular js resource as shown below:

Current implementation:

```
  function TrackResource($resource) {
    return $resource(
      'track/:type/:id',
      { type: 'info', id: '@id' },
      {
        'info': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'info', id: '@id' } },
        'live': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'live', id: null } },
        'lyrics': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'lyrics', id: '@id' } },
        'rand': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'rand', id: null } },
        'recent': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'recent', id: null } },
        'top': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'top', id: '@days' } },
        'log': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'log', id: '@id' } },
      }
    );
  }
```

So id can be null many times, so instead of passing null, I want to make id an optional param. Can that be done?

Comment: Can you omit `id:'@id'` from the second argument to the call to `$resource(...)` and also omit `id:null` in the individual routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution I have found is just not to send that parameter in the request.

Just send

`TrackResource.info({})` in case you don't want second option, it will automatically become null in query, make sure you don't mention the same in ResourceStructure:

```
  function TrackResource($resource) {
    return $resource(
      'track/:type/:id',
      { type: 'info', id: '@id' },
      {
        'info': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'info', id: '@id' } },
        'live': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'live' } },
        'lyrics': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'lyrics', id: '@id' } },
        'rand': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'rand' } },
        'recent': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'recent' } },
        'top': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'top', id: '@days' } },
        'log': { method: 'GET', params: { type: 'log', id: '@id' } },
      }
    );
  }
```